# @track decorated property not updating LWC after imperative call

Tags: lightning-web-components, rerender, imperativeapex

[image: App screenshot]

I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

I have a component that is supposed to display data after it receives an id of the exact record hence I am using an imperative call. I can see in the log that the data is received but my component is not reloading with the data.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Advisor Details">
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
        <template if:true={advisor}>
            <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                   <p>{advisor.Name}</p> 
                </lightning-layout-item>
                  <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">                    
                    <p>{advisor.Company}</p>                    
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                    <p>{advisor.Title}</p>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                    <p>{advisor.Engagement}</p>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>
            
        </template>
        <template if:false={advisor}><p>No advisor data available.</p></template>   
          
        <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

the js.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import {subscribe, MessageContext} from 'lightning/messageService';
import getCompleteAdvDetails from '@salesforce/apex/GetAdvisorRecords.getCompleteAdvDetails';
import RECORD_SELECTED_CHANNEL from  '@salesforce/messageChannel/Record_Selected__c';

export default class PartnerDetailComponent extends LightningElement {
    recordId;
    details;
    @track advisor;
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;


    subscribeToMessageChannel(){
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            RECORD_SELECTED_CHANNEL,
            (message) => this.handleMessage(message)
        );
    
    }
    handleMessage(message){
        if(message){
        this.recordId = message.recordId;        
        console.log('Received message ' + this.recordId);
--------------------------[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        //I have hardcoded the values here but the advisor property doesn't //cause the component to rerender
        let pAdv = {};
        pAdv.Name = 'Bossman';
        pAdv.Company = 'RBL';
        pAdv.Title = 'Senior Counsel';
        pAdv.Engagement = 'Advisor';
        
        this.advisor = pAdv;
-------------------

        getCompleteAdvDetails( { mentId: this.recordId})
        .then((result) => {
            this.details = result;
            if (this.details) {
                console.log('Successful details retrieval!'+ JSON.stringify(this.details));
                 this.advisor = this.details;
                        
               
                    let pAdvisor = {};
                    let fName = this.advisor.First_Name__c;
                    let lName = this.advisor.Last_Name__c;
                    pAdvisor.Name = fName + ' ' + lName;
                    pAdvisor.Id = this.advisor.Id;
                    pAdvisor.Title =this.advisor.Title__c;             
                    pAdvisor.Company = this.advisor.Company__c;
                    pAdvisor.Engagement = 'Type of Engagement '+ this.advisor.Type_of_Engagement__c;
                    // pAdvisor.Mentees = 'Number of Mentees '+element.Number_of_Mentees__c;
                    // pAdvisor.Email = 'Email '+element.Email__c;
                    // pAdvisor.Phone = 'Phone' + element.Phone__c;
                    // pAdvisor.Expertise = 'Aread of Expertise '+element.Area_ofS_Expertise__c;
                    console.log('PAdvisor ' + JSON.stringify(pAdvisor));                 
              
                this.advisor = pAdvisor ;
                console.log('Updated advisor. '+ JSON.stringify(this.advisor));

      
            }
        }) 
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('Error '+ this.error);
        });
    }
        
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.subscribeToMessageChannel();
    }
}
```

I have also tried getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]) and it was not successful. I am not sure I did it correctly though since I assumed that the advisor property used in template will be updated when I update the recordId.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

[image: Console output]

Comment: Is `advisor` property marked as track?

Comment: Could You provide more details - full js class code. `advisor` should be decoreated with @track.

Comment: Yes it is @Raul.  I have updated the js part.

Comment: Wondering if it helps to also pass the scope to the subscribe method. On another note, you should also unsubscribe the event as a best practice.

Comment: Thanks Raul. Could you explain what you mean by passing the scope? The subscribe method is working ok since it is fetching the Id as expected. I have taken note on the best practice. Will do that.

Comment: I was referring to 4th parameter of [`subscribe`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) method, but never mind I tested a minimal example and it works at my end, so not issue with scope. Could you try hardcoding the `advisor` property's value instead of making the `getCompleteAdvDetails` call, just to rule out if its an issue with the apex call?

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried that but it is still not reloading. I am updating the code to show how it looks as well as the way I have organized it. I have two components. The one on  the left has a link which on click submits an id that is then used to retrieve the data that is then displayed in the second component on the right labeled Advisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are reassigning the variable, and overwritting the actual tracked object.

You can both:

```
this.advisor.Name = 'Bossman'; //As fas as it is @tracked
```

Or:

```
this.advisor = {...pAdv};
```

Or:

```
this.advisor = Object.assign({},pAdv);
```

For not tracked variable or reassignations you need to use {} syntax or Object.assign. If you don't the change will not be noticed by the framework.

Hope it helps

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let me know, but it should work in any of that ways.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the @track annotation since you are reassigning the entire variable.
Can you try these 2 things? Deep clone the object (just as an attempt) and before assignin the value, assign it to undefined like:

```
this.advisor = undefined;
this.advisor = JSON.parse(JSON.strinify(pAdv));
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I have decided to change the design of the app. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Javier, thanks for your pointers.

I finally got it to work  in another context.

the reassignment worked like this..

```
this.displayResults = [...this.displayResults, this.searchResult];
```

The component gets rerendered and captures the new elements.